# ajax postback does not work for byte array

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, postback

I am trying to sent a `byte[]` in a postback action, but failed to get it.
Code snippets:

```
$.ajax({
        url: proxy.Model.RequestParamUrl,
        type: "Post",
        async: false,
        data: proxy.requestArgs,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (Jsondata) {
            proxy.allowPost = false;
            proxy.postSucceed = true;
            //hidden code
            return true;
        }
    });
```

While debugging, I can see `byte[]` in `proxy.requestArgs`.
But in the controller, I get null in this action result.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Index(byte[] param)
    {
//I get null in this param.
}
```

Anything I am missing out?
Any Solution

Comment: make your data: look like this: 
data: { param: proxy.requestArgs }

Answer (score 4):

You're passing data to the controller action and that action is expecting a post item named param.  So in your JS, make your ajax call look like this (note the change to data):

```
$.ajax({
    url: proxy.Model.RequestParamUrl,
    type: "Post",
    async: false,
    data: { param: proxy.requestArgs },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (Jsondata) {
        proxy.allowPost = false;
        proxy.postSucceed = true;
        //hidden code
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?
Basically, accept the data as `string` in you action and inside it convert it into `byte[]`

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Index(string param)
{
   var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(param);
}
```